# stop execution of other directive on my custom element directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a custom element directive e.g. like below

```
  <my-wrapper ng-model="values.abc" unique-check="" list="list" prop="name"> </my-wrapper>
```

This directive does require ng-model which is later being set on the inner input tag

```
  <input type="text" name="myfield" ng-model="'+attrs.ngModel+'"/>
```

the problem happening is when I check console I can see ng-model on directive is not same as ng-model on input tag.

How can I make sure that the ng-model on outer tag is not created and its created only once inside my directive.

my directive code is below

```
app.directive("myWrapper", function(){

  var templateFn = function(element, attrs){
    return '<div ng-form="myform">'+
          '<input type="text" name="myfield" ng-model="'+attrs.ngModel+'"/>'+
          '<span>(inside directive) : isDuplicate:{{myform.myfield.$error.isDuplicate}}</span>'
          '</div>';
  }

  return {
    restrict :'E',
    template : templateFn,
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: true
  }
});
```

Please note that above is just a shortened version of my directive, and I have keep scope: true because of requirement in the overall scenario.

If its not clear what I am talking about, please checkout the console of [THIS PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/WT1rqzq29NXn5A92wviA?p=preview)

I tried solutions with `terminal : true` and/or `priority : 1001` so that the ng-model is not created on the directive html but only on input tag, but none of them worked.

yes, one solution can be to replace ng-model with lets say my-model on the directive and then again add it as ng-model on input tag, but then its being used at almost 1000s of places in my app, so really wont like to replace it as such.

any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Could it be the missing `</div>`? (Long shot, I know...)  Also trying setting the priority to something other than 0.  (`priority: 0` is default, but there is tricky timing in the linking function when the final step happens priorities are ran in reverse.)  If you make a plunker it may be easier to debug.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, the above code is just a contrived example. will update the the question accordingly...

Comment: As far as I know you'll have to go with the my-model option unfortunately.

Comment: @CorySilva created the plunker...

Comment: I am really new to Angular, but trying to figure out what all things developers are doing around the stack world with angular and came across this question. Not sure whether I understood the question correctly, but why can't we just use link function to remove the attribute? Before removing it just hold on to the value. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: thanks but that wont work because ng-model is getting created even before the directive gets the chance..

Comment: The solution you're trying to avoid is the solution you should have gone with in the first place. You don't use `ngModel` so it's weird to include it. Replacing `ng-model` with `my-model` should be a matter of seconds, even with _almost 1000s of places_.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Comw7jOfmOoIk6zELeF?p=preview will it work for you..i removed parent directive div after linking function started.

Comment: @pankajparkar even with your solution in console i get `ngModel === myform.myfield: false` so both are not same, hence this is not solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

So [try this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CW5PruYJrtRw7eqLOa7b?p=preview).  Basically I made the `my-wrapper` directive pass through its simple properties onto its input tag.  For attributes that needed to be parsed, I simply parsed them and injected them into the scope create by the `my-wrapper` directive.

I am not very sure why you have a directive that wraps a form around a single input, but like you said this is a contrived example.  Personally I would change this structure, but I tried not to be too disruptive.

Hope this helps.  Maybe you can explain your intent behind this.

Comment: `one solution can be to replace ng-model with lets say my-model on the directive and then again add it as ng-model on input tag` this option I am aware of, but just wanted to avoid.  regarding one form per control, the inner directive based on input can have multiple inputs, in this simple example - I didnt want to confuse other by telling non-so-much-needed-to-know logic

Comment: The `my-model` solution seems to be easier than restructuring.  For the structure why did not not just use two `ng-repeat` directives: one over an array of forms and a second over inputs/ng-models?

Comment: its not just ng-model, I will have to do it for most of my custom directives which are based on wrapper directives. Its like a huge - very huge change for me :(, but it seems no way around it, unfortunately :( I really dont understand why the terminal/priority stuff doesnt work :(

Comment: FWIW Terminal does work correctly but your `uniqueCheck` directive errors out because you are telling it to require ngModel, but `terminal: true` specifically stops the creation of ngModel

Comment: if its stop execution of ng-model directive then it should also stop the execution of uniqueCheck directive

Comment: that plunker is not working... didnt understood what you wanted to show using that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67483/discussion-between-cory-silva-and-harishr).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using transclusion. Instead of trying to do the hard part of breaking through standard AngularJS compilation, you could just change your structure to something like:

```
<my-wrapper>
    <input name="..." ng-model="...">
</my-wrapper>
```

and make your directive expand the wrapper into your template with transcluded input inside it. (See the `transclude` option in [`$compile` documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/service/$compile).) This would increase readability of your templates as well.

---

Alternatively, if you need your directive to generate complex content (multiple inputs, etc.) all encapsulated and bound to that single `ng-model`, you could leave the `ng-model` where it is and make your directive completely encapsulated. By this I mean something like:

```
.directive('myComplexField', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                // ... (update your isolated model based on external model change)
            });
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                // ... (update external model based on your isolated model)
            });
            $scope.$watch('... (properties of your isolated model)', function () {
                // force sync (parser code above will take care of setting the real value)
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(!ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

(see [`ngModelController` documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)). You just need to be careful not to create an infinite loop between your `$parser` and `$formatter`.

---

If you're really dead set on leaving `ng-model` on your wrapper and skipping it using `priority` and `terminal`, it's [pretty simple](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyaZNQ?editors=101):

```
.directive('foo', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 2,  // ngModel priority is 1 (see the docs)
        terminal: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            $compile($element, undefined, 1)($scope);  // compiles priority *lower than 1*
        }
    };
}
```

This approach should be avoided if at all possible, because it has many apparent downsides and no real upside.

Comment: the input tag is generated dynamically, so cant use transclude

Comment: Ok. I can't really say unless I see the whole scenario, but I'd still recommend doing a clean split. If not the one I suggested, then the opposite (suggested by @CorySilva in his answer) - putting model expression in your directive's configuration.

Comment: I've extended my answer with the third alternative, useful for complex "multiple inputs to one model" logic.

Comment: sorry but this is also not helping, what I want to understand as the way terminal and priority works, or rather why they cant work in this case, I am aware of alternative solutions (few of which I had already mentioned in my question itself.) but I was looking for best possible solution, which seemed plausible using terminal/priority properties, but alas that doesnt seem to be the case

Comment: Then the answer is simply **no, you cannot do what you want with the tools you've chosen**. The purpose of `terminal` (used with `priority`) is to allow a directive to cut out its element and manually compile lower-level directives later, when inserting it somewhere (think `ng-repeat`).

Comment: thats what actually the directive is doing, manually compiling the lower level directives, check the plunker. It generates html, compiltes and replaces the existing element

Comment: @CorySilva already commented on your plunker. You don't want `ng-model` on the wrapper element to compile, yet you're trying to use its controller there in `uniqueCheck`.

Comment: Other than that, you could use `priority` & `terminal` to skip `ngModel` (give your directive `ngModel.priority + 1` and manually `$compile` with `ngModel.priority - 1`). I can't stress enough how bad a design that would be.

Comment: can you provide me example of how to do that?